# How to prove $\left(|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p\right)^{1/p}\ge 2^{1/p}\left(a^2+(p-1)b^2\right)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For real numbers $a, b$ and all $1\le p\le 2$, how to prove $$\left(|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p\right)^{1/p}\ge 2^{1/p}\left(a^2+(p-1)b^2\right)^{1/2}?$$

Answer (score 1):

let $m=|a+b|,n=|a-b|$

first we prove $\left (\dfrac{m^p+n^p}{2} \right)^2 \ge \left(p\left(\dfrac{m-n}{2}\right)^2+mn\right)^p$

WLOG, let $ m\ge n , x=\dfrac{m}{n}\ge 1  \iff  \left (\dfrac{x^p+1}{2} \right)^2 \ge \left(p\left(\dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^2+x\right)^p \iff f(x)=2\ln{\left (\dfrac{x^p+1}{2} \right)}-p\ln{\left ( \left( \dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^2+x \right)} \ge 0$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{2px((2-p)x^p+px^{p-1}-px-2+p)}{x^p(px^3+(4-2p)x^2+px)+px^3+(4-2p)x^2+px} $

$g(x)=(2-p)x^p+px^{p-1}-px-2+p, \\g'(x)=p(2-p)x^{p-1}+p(p-1)x^{p-2}-p,\\g''(x)=p(2-p)(p-1)(x-1)x^{p-2} \ge 0 \implies g'(x) \ge g'_{min}(x)=g'(1)=0 \implies g(x)\ge g(1)=0 \implies f'(x)\ge 0 \implies f(x) \ge f(1)=0$

it remains

$p\left(\dfrac{m-n}{2}\right)^2+mn \ge a^2+(p-1)b^2 \iff \dfrac{p(a^2+b^2)+(2-p)|a^2-b^2|}{2} \ge a^2+(p-1)b^2 \iff (a^2\ge b^2 \cap (a^2+(p-1)b^2 \ge a^2+(p-1)b^2)  , (a^2<b^2) \cap (b^2+(p-1)a^2 \ge a^2+(p-1)b^2 \iff (2-p)b^2 \ge (2-p)a^2)$

QED

Answer (score 0):

$\left(|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p\right)^{1/p}\ge 2^{1/p}\left(a^2+(p-1)b^2\right)^{1/2} \iff  \\ \left(\dfrac{|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p}{2}\right)^{2/p}\ge a^2+(p-1)b^2$

note RHS is a linear function of $p$,

when $p=2$, LHS=RHS,

when $p=1$, LHS$= \dfrac{a^2+b^2+|a^2-b^2|}{2} = \max{[a^2,b^2]} \ge a^2=RHS$,

which hints LHS is a concave function.

To make following proof solid,first we consider case $a=b $ :

LHS-RHS$=a^2(2^{2-\frac{2}{p}}-p) \ge 0 \iff a^2\ge 0$ and $ 2^{2-\frac{2}{p}}-p \ge 0 \iff 2^{2-\frac{2}{p}}$ is concave function,

so this is true and "=" will hold when $a=0$ or $p=1$ or $p=2$

when $a\not=b$:

**EDIT**:

LHS$=(a-b)^2*\left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)^{2/p},u=\dfrac{|a+b|}{|a-b|}$, now we prove $k(p)=\left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)^{2/p}$is concave when $p\ge1$.

let $f(p)=\ln{\left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)^{2/p}}=\dfrac{2}{p} \ln{ \left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)},k(p)=e^{f(p)} $ is concave $\iff k''(p)<0 \iff e^{f(p)}((f'(p))^2+f''(p)) <0 \iff g(p)=\left(\dfrac{ 2u^p\ln{u}}{(u^p+1)p}-\dfrac{2\ln{\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}}}{p^2}\right)^2+ 2\left(\dfrac{u^p p^2(\ln{u})^2-2(u^{2p}+u^p)p \ln{u}+2(u^p+1)^2 \ln{\dfrac{(u^p+1)}{2}}}{(u^p+1)^2p^3}\right)<0 $ when $p\ge 1$

**EDIT2:**

$g'(p)=2f'(p)f''(p)+f'''(p)$

now we prove $f'(p)>0,f''(p)<0,f'''(p)<0$

$f'(P)=2\dfrac{u^2\ln{u^p}-(u^p+1)\ln{\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}}}{(u^p+1)p^2}>0 \iff u^2\ln{u^p}-(u^p+1)\ln{\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}}>0 \iff x=u^p,h_1(x)=x\ln{x}-(x+1)\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}>0 $

$h'_1(x)=\ln{\dfrac{2x}{x+1}}$, it is trivial that $h_1(x)\ge 0 $

$f''(p)<0 \iff u^p p^2(\ln{u})^2-2(u^{2p}+u^p)p \ln{u}+2(u^p+1)^2 \ln{\dfrac{(u^p+1)}{2}}<0 \iff x=u^p,h_2(x)=x(\ln{x})^2-2(x+1)x\ln{x}+2(x+1)^2\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}<0 $

$h'_2(x)=4x\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2x}}-4\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}+(\ln{x})^2,h''_2(x)=2\left(2\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2x}}+\dfrac{\ln{x}}{x}\right),$$h'''_2(x)=-2\dfrac{(x+1)\ln{x}+x-1}{x^2(x+1)}$

note : $t(x)=(x+1)\ln{x}+x-1$ is mono increasing function, so $h'''(x)$ has only one zero point $x=1 \implies h''_2(x) $ has max point $h''(1)=0 \implies h_2(x) \le0 \implies f''(p)<0$

$f'''(p)=-2\dfrac{(u^{2p}-u^p)(\ln{u^p})^3+3(u^{2p}+u^p)(\ln{u^p})^2-6(u^p+1)^2\ln{u}+6(u^{p}+1)^3\ln{\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}}}{(u^p+1)^3p^4}$

$h_3(x)=x(x-1)(\ln{x})^3+3(x^2+x)(\ln{x})^2+6(x+1)^2((x+1)\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}-\ln{x})$

it is trivial that $x(x-1)(\ln{x})^3 \ge 0,3(x^2+x)(\ln{x})^2 \ge 0, 6(x+1)^2>0$

$t_3(x)=(x+1)\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}-\ln{x},t'_3(x)=\ln{\dfrac{x+1}{2}}+1-\dfrac{1}{x} \implies t_3(x) \ge 0 \implies h_3(x)>0 \implies f'''(p)<0$

$j(u)=g(p=1,u)=\dfrac{(2h_1(u))^2+2h_2(u)}{(u+1)^2}<0 \iff j_1(u)=(2h_1(u))^2+2h_2(u)<0 $

$j'_1(u)=2(2h_1(u))*2h'_1(u)+2h'_2(u), j''_2(u)=8(h'_1(u))^2+8h_1(u)h''_1(u)+2h''_2(u)$

it remains  $g(u,p=1)<0$. (Actually $ g(u,p=1)$ is concave ,  $g''_{u} <0$.)  ( I will go on later .)

so $k(p)$ is concave when $p\ge 1$

Comment: You want to show $\left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)^{2/p}$ is concave, but it is not equivalent to $f$ is concave. Eg. $x^2$ is convex, but $\ln x^2$ is concave.

Comment: Indeed, $f(u)=\left(\dfrac{u^p+1}{2}\right)^{2/p}$ is convex for $1\le p\le 1$, $u>0$.

Comment: @Fischer,you are right. i made a mistake to take $ln k(p)$. so the problem is become hard now for me. :(