# when index is irrational number with inequality

Tags: inequality, irrational-numbers

> Let $x>0$, show that
>   $$x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+1\ge 3\left(\dfrac{1+x}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{3}}$$

we consider
$$f(x)=2^{\sqrt{3}}(x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+1)- 3(1+x)^{\sqrt{3}}$$
use computer in fact $f(x)\ge 0,x>0$,see [Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%28x%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%2Bx%5E%7B%5Cdfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D%2B1%29-+3%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D)
we have
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\left(2^{\sqrt{3}}x^{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-1}\left(
2x^{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+1\right)-6(x+1)^{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)$$
for this  index irrational numbers,

what approaches do you think, I could take to solving the next step?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question here. What does “for this index irrational numbers” even mean ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{x^{\sqrt3}+x^{\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}}+1}{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{x^{\sqrt3+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}}}=x^{\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}}$$ Since $$\dfrac{1+x}{2}\ge x^{\dfrac{1}{2}}$$ I loose it.

Comment: @Nilan,and  this also can't solve it.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to try to prove more: Like $x^{2p}+x^p+1\geq\frac{3}{2^p}(x^2+1)^p$, for $x\geq0$ and $p\geq\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$. For $p=\sqrt{3}$ we get our inequality. In this form it is more apparent that what is important for the exponent is to make the leading coefficient of the right-hand side $\leq1$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655530/how-to-prove-leftabpa-bp-right1-p-ge-21-p-lefta2p-1b2-ri/915592#915592, $m=x^{1/2},n=1$,it should  solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, we find a special point: $\dfrac{1}{3}> \left(\dfrac{1+x}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{3}} \implies x<2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}-1=0.0606 \implies x<0.06, $ the inequality is always true.

both side take log, we have: $\ln{\dfrac{x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+1}{3}}\ge \ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{3}}},f(x)=\ln{\dfrac{x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+1}{3}}-\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{3}}}$

now we need to prove $f'(x)>0$ when $x>1$ and $f'(x)<0$ when $1>x>0.06$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}(2x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}(1-x)-2x)}{(x^{\sqrt{3}}(2x^2+2x)+x^{(\sqrt{3}/2)}(2x^2+2x)+2x^2+2x) }$

$g(x)=2x^{\sqrt{3}}+x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}(1-x)-2x$

for $x>1$,  $g(x)>0 \iff x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\dfrac{x}{x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}>\dfrac{x-1}{2} \cap \dfrac{x}{x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}<x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}}\iff x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}}>\dfrac{x-1}{2}$

for $0.06<x<1$,prove $g''>0$ which mean $g(x)$ will get max at $g(1)$ or $g(.06)$, if both end $\le 0 \implies g(x) \le 0$

I will not goto details because this is not so difficult.

Edit: a more straight way to prove $g(x)<0 \iff x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\dfrac{x}{x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}<\dfrac{x-1}{2} $ is:

LHS$=h(x)=x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\dfrac{x}{x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}},h''(x)=x^{-2}(\dfrac{3}{2}-\sqrt{3})(x^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-x^{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}})>0 \cap (x<1) \implies h(x) <y=\dfrac{h(1)-h(0.06)}{1-.06}(x-1)+h(1)=0.562(x-1)<0.5(x-1)$

the tricky here is when $x$ is small enough, $g(x)>0$, that is why we exclude small $x$ at beginning.

Comment: It's nice  answer  !+1

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = 2z+1$ so that $\frac{1+x}{2} = 1+z$. I also set $p=\sqrt{3}/2$ for commodity. Then the inequality becomes
$$ (1+2z)^{2p} + (1+2z)^p + 1 - 3 (1+z)^{2p} \geq 0.$$

**The reasoning below this point is false, since $\binom{x}{n}$, for $x$ not an integer and $n > x$, is negative. Actually, even the third coefficient of the power series expansion is $(12 \sqrt{3}-21)/2$, which is negative. I leave this as the trace of a failed attempt...**

Expanding as power series of $z$, this becomes
$$ \sum \left((2^n-3)\binom{2p}{n}+2^n \binom{p}{n}\right) z^n \geq 0. $$
(Except the constant coefficient, which is zero).
So we might show the result at least for $0 \leq z < 1$ (this is the radius of convergence) if we were able to prove that, for $n \geq 1$,
$$ (2^n-3) \binom{2p}{n} + 2^n \binom{p}{n} \geq 0, \quad p = \sqrt{3}/2.$$
For $n \geq 2$ this is obvious since $2^n \geq 3$. We manually check that this is also true for $n = 1$:
$$ (2^1-3)\binom{2p}{1} + 2^1 \binom{p}{1} = -\sqrt{3}+2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 0.$$

This proves the result for $z \in [0, 1[$ and hence $x \in [1,3[$. It remains to show :

- the case where $x \geq 3$: this should be easier, since both functions are further apart in this region. (The hardest part was the osculating point at $x=1$).
- the case where $0 < x < 1$. However, both sides are quite symmetric with respect to $x \mapsto 1/x$, so that I expect that we may easily deduce it from the case $x > 1$.

Comment: If $F(x)$ is analytic on $x>0$ and $F(x)=\sum a_nx^n$, with $a_n\geq0$, for $|x|<R$, then $F(x)\geq0$ for $x>0$. The reason is that we can consider the series $\sum a_n(x+a)^n$ centered at another point $0<a<R$ inside the convergence radius $|R|$. When you expand in powers of $x$ we get again a series with non-negative coefficients, showing that the function is non-negative in a neighborhood of $a$. We know this series will converge in a disc that goes a little outside of $|x|<R$ because we know that $F(x)$ is analytic at each point of $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question I was wondering about and completes the proof.

Comment: There is something suspicious, though, that I might look at later, and that is about the values of $p$. The original inequality doesn't seem to hold for all values of $\sqrt{3}$, but I don't see the proof reflecting that.

Comment: Yes and it is: for $n$ large enough $\binom{p}{n}$ will be <0 (for fixed, non-integer $p$).  Actually, the third coefficient of the series is $5 \binom{2p}{3}+ 8 \binom{p}{3} = (12\sqrt{3}-21)/2 < 0$. So the power series expansion is false.

Comment: Well... at least it proves it is non-negative in some small neighborhood of $x=1$.

Comment: I would still be happy to find a solution, since (a) this problem bugs me (cf. my first failed attempt, where I messed up the signs of what seemed to be a perfect application of convexity), and (b) the linked answer is really scary.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't answer this question. It has some similar flavor but that's all.